# How to move/change the position/order of an JavaScript Object array(JSON)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Let's say I have this javascript object array,

```
[{a:'a', b:2, c:true}, {a:'b', b:3, c:true}, {a:'a1', b:3, false}]
```

Let's say I need to move the object at index 0 to 2. I have tried this function with no luck.

```
   Array.prototype.move = function (old_index, new_index) {
    if (new_index >= this.length) {
        var k = new_index - this.length;
        while ((k--) + 1) {
            this.push(undefined);
        }
    }
    this.splice(new_index, 0, this.splice(old_index, 1)[0]);
  };
```

Comment: with this, are you swapping? or moving and replacing the existing

Comment: @YusafKhaliq, just similar to the above move function but with js object array.

Comment: like this ? http://jsfiddle.net/YJbXA/

Comment: @YusafKhaliq, no. JS object array.

Comment: it's same principle if you replace the strings with your json

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YJbXA/1/

Comment: @YusafKhaliq, change the order will affect all(or less than all) elements. This is not just simple.

Comment: from what i got all you wanted was to swap indexes in the array, and that is simple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The object array is not correct, it needs the 'c' variable in the last item:

```
[{a:'a', b:2, c:true}, {a:'b', b:3, c:true}, {a:'a1', b:3, c:false}];
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/WgLKc/1/

Comment: I just tested it, it does work. If it doesn't for you, you should explain the expected behaviour more clearly.

Comment: @user960567 I did, in chrome and IE9. The order after moving is [ {a:'b', b:3, c:true}, {a:'a1', b:3, c:false}, {a:'a', b:2, c:true}], as expected.